# Grammar induction from grammaticality rules

Tags: computational-linguistics, semantics, grammar, generative-grammar

Let's have formalisation of grammaticality judgments in some deduction system. Is it possible to learn/induce grammar from rules that govern grammaticality judgments? Is there theory, that connects grammar rueles as stated in the everyday grammar books and that usually make references to the semantics from the one side and more or less formal grammar (e.g. context free grammar) from the other side. How all that is connected to grammaticality judgments?

Comment: i suppose you've looked at the relevant Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar_induction

Comment: I know about induction and I wonder why the problem is still unsolved. But my question was about the fact that grammar books state grammar rules, e.g. the use of a vs the, quite differently from rules of formal grammars. I am aware of article about model theoretic semantics of grammaricality judgments (I am in gym now and I have no chance to post link) and I wonder wheter there is wider research trend along these two lines of representation and reasoning?

Comment: I don't know the answers to your questions.  These are subjects of research (and disagreement).